# Friend's PC working in my home, not in his

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, hardware-failure, bsod

Advisors!

My friend has a PC whose cabinet keeps shocking and it regularly keeps making problems from time to time, like

• Disk read error
• Hard Drive not found
• Blank Grey Screen when booting
• Games stuck on loading
• BSODs

None of his wires are loose, they are all new. But unplugging-replugging them always solved the problem for some days, until a new problem showed up. So he sent me his PC to diagnose, but even after 2 weeks, I haven't found any problems. I am actually stress-testing it, but every component seems ok.

My findings were,

• The PC cabinet stopped shocking as soon as I brought it in my home.

• Hard Disk has a single bad sector.

Is it possible that the problem is somehow with his home?

Comment: You write about stop shocking but never explained it was shocking. Can you edit your question to make it clear? [click to edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1674367/edit)

Comment: Done, made the edit

Comment: One way to determine if it is the house is if your friend sets up the pc in another room, using another plug. This will then help reduce if issue is house or room (plug socket) etc.

Comment: Tried, it's not working. It does boot up, but new problems keep arriving.

Comment: It does not seem just a HDD issue, because atleast then some problems should have been permanent.

Comment: It seems clear that the problem is not in the system, it's in the electric circuit of your friend's house. It's not stable. I'm betting that if it was properly measured by a professional electrician they'd find all kinds of fluctuations - for example just turning a neon light on or off, powering up a printer, fridge / freezer compressor turning on or off can cause spikes and other similar fluctuations in the mains power.

Comment: Thank you so much to all of you for helping me. If it's simply an earthing problem, can putting the cabinet on ground improve anything? The problem is that we don't have professional electricians in our village.

Comment: If it is electrical I would suggest an electrician... Maybe it is safe as it is?

Comment: Thanks for giving me your worthy time.

Comment: If the electrician doesn't report a fault let us know but it is very hard to diagnose.

Comment: The problem's not necessarily earthing, there are a lot of possible issues in poorly constructed electric circuit. Earthing's also not quite as simple. Earth provides the 0V reference for the circuit, determined by the current flowing through the circuit multiplied by the impedance of the grounding system. Which  means that "earthing" of a circuit is relevant to that circuit alone. Pulling power from circuit A but earthing to circuit B has a  good chance of introducing ground potential difference, which in turn can lead to actual hardware damage.

Comment: Here's one resource talking about earthing and potential differences: https://www.cablinginstall.com/cable/article/16465312/ground-potentials-and-damage-to-lan-equipment

Comment: Really sorry that I didn't mention it before. Grounding is not installed in my house even, yet it's safe to touch the cabinet regardless of where I place it. Can you tell me, how is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's very knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an earthing/wiring issue and is really something an electrician needs to look into.  What you have described could be dangerous and unsafe to fix.

You have not mentioned where you are (matters from an electrical code pov. You might want to confirm this.  Relatedly, do you have a multimeter ?

If you are getting shocks  that means electricity has an alternative path to ground. One thing you can try us getting the thickest cable you can find and a big metal pole/rod.  Bang the pole  nearly all the way into the ground, and run the cable from the pole to a metal part of the computer case.  This will ground the case and may be useful and safer then it is now.  Really though, a sparky should be looking into this and possibly correcting this at the mains board.

Comment: Thanks David, I will surely do that. By the way, me and my friend are living in India.

Comment: And sorry that I didn't mention it before. Grounding is not installed in my house, yet it's safe to touch the cabinet regardless of where I place it. Can you tell me, how is that possible?

Comment: Im not expert enough to answer your questions, but (at least in many places)  Grond and Neutral should be tied to each other appropriately.  If you are getting a shock it is likely that ground and neutral arn't.  Most devices dont need a ground to work. A floor is not the same as earth/ground. For example a wooden floor could be insulated from real ground.  Its also possible the shock you are receiving is not electrically related and could be static electricity - which can stuff up electronics.  Nylon carpets can do this.

Comment: The floor is actually cement in both houses. And there are no carpets anywhere. The shock is constant. And my landlord just told me that grounding is not installed in my house. Can't say what is going on in my friend's house.

Comment: Wish me luck so that I can find the cause. Thanks

Comment: @ChandanaSamanta - Unless your landlord is an electrician they probably don't actually know the answer to the question you asked them.  If you are being shocked, while a device is plugged into your house electricity, that is a sign of a grounding issue with the house.

Comment: No, I literally opened up my outlet. There is no ground wire.